# How did the number of unknowns change in the Dirac equation?

Tags: classical-mechanics, dirac-equation, degrees-of-freedom

So I haven't seen this argument addressed in any textbook which makes me doubt it's legitimacy. Here goes:

Since Newton's $F=ma$ is essentially a second-order differential equation. Any equation of dynamics must have $2$ unknowns. Since, it must reduce to Newton's second law under appropriate limits. But wait there is the Dirac equation which are in some sense $4$ equations of first order differential equations. I know the Weyl decomposition allows for decomposition into $2$ Weyl spinors but there are other decompositions which lead me confused. How does one start with $4$ unknowns take limits or some other operations or considerations and then somehow ends up with an equation with $2$ unknowns (Newtonian Mechanics).

Comment: What does newtons law have to do with the dirac equation? They are separate dynamical equations and one cannot be reduced to the other.

Comment: The classical limit of fermions is a limit in which the number of fermions becomes very large, and the Planck constant, ℏ, becomes very small. In this limit, the fermions can be approximated by classical particles, and their behavior can be described by classical mechanics.

Comment: I don't think I agree with your statement as Fermions always have to obey PEP. This is why grassman-valued complex numbers are used in field theory and these objects do not have any classical analogue.

Comment: @emirsezik So I think I had confused myself. The classical limit is obtained by decomposing into Weyl spinors (to get the Pauli equation). There are 2 object and 4 unknowns. Where as in Newtonian dynamics we have 1 object and 2 knowns. No contradiction

Answer (score 0):

Schrödinger has two real fields, the time derivative links real and imagianry parts. The Pauli theory adds a unitary matrix representing the quantum analog of a symmetric spinning top and acting on a complex 2-vector with 4 real field components. Dirac adds two more degrees of freedom for positive and negative frequencies. The real algebra always yields two independent components per complex vector degree of freedom, so that Newtons experimental setting, that for each degree of freedom amplitude and velocity of amplitude can be prepared indepently.

Answer (score 0):

The initial conditions for the dynamics of Dirac  particles require knowing both  both the initial position and initial velocity (as with Newtonian particles)  but also the initial direction of the particle's spin (two polar angles). Therefore 4 initial conditions.